# JQM simpledialog: how to prompt for a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a

```
mode: "number"
```

option for jquery.mobile.simpledialog.js?

I.e: I need to ask user for a number, and I would like mobile keyboard to be in "numerical-only mode"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the numerical keyboard, add `type="number"` to an `input` tag. In SimpleDialog, you could use a freeform display, something like:

```
$(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function() {
  $('<div>').simpledialog2({
    mode: 'blank',
    headerText: 'Some Stuff',
    headerClose: true,
    blankContent : 
      "<input type='number' /> " +
      "<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>"
  })
})​
```

On a browser that supports it, when trying to enter something in the `input` tag, you'll get a number keypad. This won't limit a user on a desktop browser from entering text though. You'd have to check for that separately.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EepnZ/1/) example.